# Maintain div scroll position after ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have created a plain asp.net application for web chat.

After every chat box (div) refresh, it scroll's to top. I want to maintain it to its current position.

Tried, but doing something wrong. Getting var div and "hdndiv" values null inside windows.load. Help me out!!

```
<script>

window.onload = function () {
    debugger;
    var div = document.getElementById("divMessages");
    var hdndiv_position = document.getElementById("hdndiv_position");
    var position = parseInt('<%=Request.Form["hdndiv_position"] %>');
    if (isNaN(position)) {
        position = 0;
    }
    div.scrollTop = position;
    div.onscroll = function () {
        div_position.value = div.scrollTop;
    };
};
```

```
<table style="width: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="divMessages" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word; border: 1px solid #ddd; overflow: scroll; " runat="server">
                </div>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFromUserId" Value="-1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFromUserName" Value="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnToUserId" Value="-1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnToUserName" Value="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnScrollPos" Value="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdndiv_position" Value="" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChat" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Width="100%" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" CssClass="btn" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSend_Click" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: and there is no element by id "hdndiv" . so i guess you are getting null.Just check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As question is related to `asp.net` ,  In web-form you can maintain the Scroll Postion for that Particular page with the following attribute:

In page directive you need to set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`

Ex:

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

with Page Attribute it looks as follows

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

**Edit:** For Update Panel please refer the following link

https://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/

Content taken from above link

[image]

Comment: as mentioned he is using ajax. Not posting back entire page to server.So as long as the element's HTML is not updated . It should not go to its initial postion

Comment: Tried but not working.
At Runtime, id of the div tag is changing and if I tried to get it with...

 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        debugger;
        var div = document.getElementById(<%= divMessages.ClientID %>);
            if (div!=null && div.innerHTML != null) {
                XPos = div.scrollLeft;
                yPos = div.scrollTop;
            }
        }

I am getting the id by divMessages.clientid, but still I am getting document.getElementById() as null in var div..

Comment: @rahuldesai you need to access the div like this  `var div = document.getElementById("<%= divMessages.ClientID %>");` because u missed quotation within the id

Comment: @rahuldesai NP  Happy to Help

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a thing about asp.net, but here is how i helped another user of stackoverflow:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzfn7mun/1/

```
$('.target').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $('.icon-box.active').offset().top - 
        $('.icon-box.active').parent('div').position().top
});
```

You could use the :last-child selector to do the same thing, and set animate() duration to something like 1ms.

Also what you can do, is on chatbox refresh, give an ID to the last message, and use

```
window.location.href = "#msgID";
```

But i am not sure how it will work inside a scrollable div, you will have to test it.

Hope you can make some progress with these bits!